# Ghostscript SVG output device

Tags: pdf, svg, ghostscript

I'm led to believe that it's possible to output from Ghostscript to SVG, as described on [this blog post](http://machinesplusminds.blogspot.co.uk/2011/02/converting-pdf-to-svg-that-doesnt-suck.html):

`gs -dBATCH -dSAFER -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=svg -sOutputFile=Logo.svg Logo.pdf`

However, I just get "Unknown device: svg"

I am using Ghostscript 9.06

My question is: where do I get the svg device, and how do I install it? (Red Hat x64)

So far I have tried googling (many dead ends but no real mention of this output device) and looking on the [Ghostscript website](http://www.ghostscript.com).

Answer (score 6):

If you do gs -? the usage will give you a list of available devices. Presumably your build doesn't include the svg device, in which case you will need to rebuild your executable with that support included.

Comment: Yes, it's not there in the available devices, that is my problem. However I cannot find out where to get the device from. It's no problem to rebuild with the device, if only I could find the device in the first place!

Comment: The device is supplied as source in the Ghostscript Git repository, if you get the source from there it should be present, and should build in by default unless you take action to prevent it. NB the device is deprecated.

Comment: what a shame :(

Answer (score 2):

I do have `svg` as one of my available devices. It does something a little different with the output than you expect. Specifically, it sends the file to standard error instead of to the output file you modified. Set up your command line like this for the special case:

```
gs -dBATCH -dSAFER -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=svg Logo.pdf 2>Logo.svg
```

You may or may want to look into the `-q` flag, which will suppress the usual standard output.